# Android Themed Launcher activity (Splash Screen) with new techniques and animations

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, splash-screen

I know it is the basic question and has been asked millions of time but there is something that is different that I want to talk about.

First let us talk about how to implement the splash screen. There are three ways to implement and with one having some benefits over other. However there are some discouraged ways to implement it also. Please read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-best-way-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-android-16f9096bf827) article for the possible ways to do it.

so I am creating my activity background theme as splash activity just like following using layer list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="144dp"
    android:height="144dp"/>
 </layer-list>
```

**So in thins I am showing the app icon successfully. But I want to attach a text also with it like whatsapp doing. So here is I am with my 2 basic questions**

> 1. How to show Text with App icon in layer list (Please don't tell me to make image with text, I have seen whatsapp launcher screen and
>      they are doing it differently)
> 2. Secondly how to animate the app icon in layer-list. For reference see Facebook launcher screen. They are animating their logo in app
>      start up. How they are doing that??

**Please let me know what are the new techniques of doing this??**